# Making a payment system (Game) (Solution)

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, int

I am trying to make a simple 'Idle' game where you click build, and you get cash, and when you have enough cash you can buy upgrades like automatic building, or cash generators.

I need it to take the int I have for cash `int cash = 0;` and check if it has the right amount, I am working out the amount for each generator as [Generators x 15 = pay] however to buy the first generator its free, since [Generators[0] x 15 = 0], I.E. Zero times anything will always equal 0, how can I make it so `if (cash < pay)` `int pay = Hammers * 15;`

Comment: @Sinatr please tell me how this is opinion based, I had a problem, I solved it, and I decided to share it with others, please explain for me.

Comment: I personally voted as "too broad", only by reading the title. Unfortunately it is not clear to me what problem exactly you are solving, I could as well vote "unclear": *"I set the int of the item they are buying to 0 at the start"* - what `int`? *"I need to make sure they have the amount to pay for it"* - that's just one condition, aka `if`. Even by reading the answer I can't understand the problem and the reason for question. Btw, if you would ask question correctly you may end up with better solution from someone else.

Comment: @Sinatr first of all, I need no other solution, this works, why would I want someone else's solution if I made my own? (The pride from creating a solution is quiet euphoric) and as for the question I will clear it up, as you know it was originally a question that answered itself in question, but due to a comment I split it up, I will edit the question again to clear that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a popular idle game called cookie clicker, there are "Cursor's" which give you auto generated currency via a timer, but they need to make sure the initial amount of "Cursor's" is 0, I had the same thing on my game but it was called "Hammer's" so, here is the solution.

```
int pay = hammers * 15 + 15;
if (hammers == 0)
{
    if (cash >= 15)
    {
        money.Text = cash; 
        hammers += 1;
        cash -= 15;
    }
    else if (cash <= 15)
    {
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "ERROR: You do not have enough cash to buy this!";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
     }
 }
 else if (Hammers >= 1)
 {
     if (cash < pay)
     {
         notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Error: You do not have enough cash to buy this!"; notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
     }
     else if (cash >= pay)
     {
         money.Text = cash;
         hammers += 1;
         cash -= pay;
     }
  }
```

Enjoy!

Comment: If `hammers = 0` then `pay = 15`, so the `else` part of the code would still be valid. Also, inner `if-else` block should use only `else`, not `else if`.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn The way I did it works fine, so I guess its just preference, neither affects the game play.

Comment: It works :) I have no doubt, it's just to simplify the code a little :)